# Rich preview of Stack Overflow for Teams questions in slack

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is there a way to have SO for Teams links dropped into the slack channel of the associated company (ie, assume that an integration has been set up) display something other than the log in banner?

This would make things easier for us as we wouldn't need to explain the link that we're posting.

eg:

[image: example]

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. I was hoping that there would be a way with the Slack integration with SO to set up that (limited) access to private content in some way.

Comment: An app could add custom [link unfurling](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling), as Slack calls it, so this can be done. I don't think it currently exists though.

Comment: Given SO-for-teams RO API, could potentially write a small bot / lambda that does this, completely external from SO.

Answer (score 4):

We have some changes in the works to improve our Slack integration - including link unfurling (i.e. rich preview within Slack). We're not sure on exact ship date yet, but it'll be on the weeks scale rather than months.

Comment: Excellent. I put together a small slackbot to do this for us in the meantime. The code isn't at a level I'd be happy open sourcing, however.